# Which option is better, MSAL.js or OpenIdConnect nuget package at Web API

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We have a SharePoint publishing site with anonymous access hosted on internet. As per the latest requirements, we need to implement user login (AzureAD, Microsoft personal and work accounts, and more) for some pages within the portal.

There are two approaches we have come up with:

1. Using msal.js file. Implementing login of user at client side itself and calling Partner Center Web API with user token to check the validity of the user plus performing required operations.
2. Create a Web API with with Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect nuget package at Web API end to implement login and also use it for doing out required operation of retrieving and modifying data from the backend.

Which approach may work best in our scenario?
Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between these two approaches is that they are using the different flows to integrate with the identity data provider.

The second approach that using the server-side code is using the **authorization code grant flow** which is a stand flow to interact with identity data provider.

The first approach that using the msal.js is using the implicit flow.  is a simplified authorization code flow optimized for clients implemented in a browser using a scripting language such as JavaScript.  In the implicit flow, instead of issuing the client an authorization code, the client is issued an access token directly.

More detail the flows using the OAuth 2.0 are defined in the [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-8).

Comment: Just to add, [here's](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi-v2) a great sample using MSAL.js.